# How to install twig localizeddate filter?

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I have PHP 5.5.9 and I activated `php_intl.dll` exyention and set its configuration in the active php.ini as the following:

```
[intl]
intl.default_locale = ar
; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error
; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.
; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.
;intl.error_level = E_WARNING
```

When I try the following twig code:

```
{{ item.get_date('j F Y | g:i a')|localizeddate('medium', 'none', locale) }}
```

I got a fatal error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'The filter "localizeddate" does not exist in "index.html" at line 53'
>   in

The official documentation [there](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html) does not show how to install or add this filter to twig. I use simple PHP application without Symfony. The twig version 1.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`twig/extensions`](https://packagist.org/packages/twig/extensions) composer package, the github repo is at [fabpot/Twig-extensions](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions).

You mention you're using twig standalone, then you must have a `Twig_Environment` object. It has an `addExtension` method, you need to call it, passing a new instance of the Intl extension:

```
$env->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl());
```